# Animated CSS radial gradient has a visible boundary

Tags: html, css, css-animations

So I'm trying to animate (moving up form bottom) a radial gradient behind other HTML controls.

HTML body has a red color. **updated color to black**

Gradient is in a `div`  with the following style:

```
.bg {
overflow: hidden;
position: auto;
height: 100%;
left: 0;
right: 0;
top: 0;
bottom: 0;
background: radial-gradient(circle, rgba(255, 255, 255, .3) 0%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 100%);


-webkit-animation-name: animatedBackground;
-webkit-animation-duration: 2.5s;}
```

So now when the gradient moves behind the HTML controls there is a visible perimeter.

[image]

You can observe that there is a border like thing (highlighted in yellow).

I'm trying to get rid of this border so that gradient appears as just a radial thing may be faded/blurred on edges, moving in background.

Is it possible ?

Am I doing something wrong?

**Added Fiddle**

https://jsfiddle.net/bxr53dx4/1/

Comment: Your position is set to Auto... You have no width. You have no height when in Auto. Change to absolute to cover the entire screen or give your .bg an actual height.

Comment: changed it to absolute. its same thing.

Comment: i added fiddle you can have a look.

Comment: It looks about right? What is it suppose to do at the end... Is there an existing example somewhere?

Comment: no it doesn't look like as i am required. it has the visible boundary as it highlighted in yellow in the image above.

Comment: Please check your demo, there is no visible border here.

Comment: can you please send the fiddle link you have.,

Comment: i have updated the link with black color. you can see it clearly.

Comment: What browser are you using?? I am chrome v.46 No border

Comment: Version 57.0.2987.133 (64-bit)